# stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: no deprecation warning

Tags: ios, xcode, deprecated

I don't receive deprecations warning regarding `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` method in XCode. 
I have the deployment target iOS 6.0. 
I receive other deprecations warning, for other functions, but none for this one.

In the build settings the warnings are enabled Build Settings -> Warning -> Deprecated Functions is YES
In the Build Phases settings Compile Sources i don't have any compiler flags enabled for any files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it's declared in UIImage.h:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight;
```

Here's what a deprecated method name typically looks like:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(2_0, 7_0, "Use -sizeWithAttributes:");
```

For a warning to appear, one of the `NS_DEPRECATED` macros from `NSObjCRuntime.h` (or one of the availability macros from `AvailabilityMacros.h`) must be present.

This is probably considered a bug, and should be reported on http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I remember that i received deprecations warning regarding this function, in earlier XCode versions